# Non-www connection refused issue

Tags: config

I have a strange issue on my installation.

It works fine as [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) but if I redirect to non-www in the .htaccess, it redirects but gives me 'Connection Refused'. the same happens if I go to http://domain.com.

Any idea's what could cause this? The URL in the config/general.php is http://www.domain.com. Could this be the cause?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds more like a web server configuration or DNS issue. Does your www record resolve to the same IP address, and is the same VirtualHost (or equivalent) being used for both addresses?

If that's all checking out, the next thing to check is if it's a http vs https thing - I know that sounds trivial but not noticing the flip has caught me out so many times!

Comment: You Sir, are a champion. Dbl-chcked the DNS and sure as <xxxxx> the www and non-www are pointing to different IP addresses .